# Importing a private key (paper wallet) to Bitcoin Core client, while offline, is not actually importing

Tags: bitcoin-core, paper-wallet, private-key-import, offline-transactions

Trying to import a paper wallet to bitcoin core, while not having a fully synced node.

I've used: `importprivkey 1Lblablablablabla "MyLabel" false`
It returns "null", which I understand means successful import.

But then when I use `dumpprivkey` with the associated public address, it says there is no private key associated with the address.

I also look in the GUI and can't find any clue as to where that private key has been imported.

So basically the wallet is not giving me errors of failed import, but also not actually importing the private key.
What should I do?

Comment: What command did you use to import the key? It sounds like you just imported a bitcoin address, not a private key.

Comment: I wrote the exact command, importprivkey "private_key" (without the quotes). I'm not going to write the actual private key here, obviously.

Comment: does the private key you imported start with a '1'? If so, that sounds like it is a bitcoin address, not a privkey. You are right to not post what the privkey is exactly, but it may be helpful to describe it (ie, what character does it start with? how long of a string is it?), to ensure you're attempting to import a key with the correct format.

Comment: Compare the length, mix of character types and initial character of your private key value with examples in [private key](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key) and [address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Invoice_address) - this will help you discover if the value you have is one or the other. Also any small mistake in typing will be important.

Comment: It starts with L3y... I can see how my first example key written here was misleading starting with a 1. But I am using a proper private key for sure..

Comment: Does [`dumpwallet`](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/101767/13866) show anything relevant?

Comment: Actually yes I manage to see the imported private key in that dump file!

Comment: Ok from the dump file it's clear that I was using the wrong PUBLIC address and that's why it didn't give me a private key back... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`dumpwallet`](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/101767/13866) to examine the wallet's contents after importing the private key.

(for completeness, since comments are disposable)